# Сформировать массив данных с инпутов c помощью JQ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть у меня input с которых нужно брать `.val()` и сформировать массив типа: `[0 => [10:30, 15:00], 1 => [9:15, 17:00], ... ], где 0, 1, 2, ... - номера дней недели`
Прошу совета как это лучше реализовать. Сейчас я создал по 4 инпута для каждого дня недели. 2 инпута для временни начала и еще 2 для конца.

```
<div class="work-schedule-title">Понедельник</div>
<div class="work-schedule-time">
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <span class="space">-</span>
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="monday">
</div>

<div class="work-schedule-title">Вторник</div>
<div class="work-schedule-time">
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <span class="space">-</span>
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
</div>
```

[image: inputs]

Comment: было бы не плохо показать html код

Comment: @splash58 Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то попробуйте так:

```
    <div class="work-schedule-title">Понедельник</div>
<div class="work-schedule-time">
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <span class="space">-</span>
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="monday">
    <input type="hidden" name="time" value="10:30, 15:00">
</div>

<div class="work-schedule-title">Вторник</div>
<div class="work-schedule-time">
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <span class="space">-</span>
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <span> : </span>
    <input type="text" name="tuesday">
    <input type="hidden" name="time" value="10:30, 15:00">
</div>

    var time = [];

$('input[name="time"]').each(function () {
    var tmp = $(this).val().split(',');

    time.push([trim(tmp[0]), trim(tmp[1])]);
});
```

Comment: чучуть по другому сделал, но все равно спасибо)